# Yii Multiple Select Values Find() Function

Tags: php, select, find, yii

I have a multiple select element, I need searching in the database with all values selected on the select  element. It's just one table, 
How can I use find() function with multiple values for a attribute table??
Right now the find() function, it will wait for a single value but it should be N values.
Is there an easier way to do that in yii.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you're not being clear enough about your problem, but I guess that the function `findAll()` could help you: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord/#findAll-detail